# disk full with large partition and small root filesystem

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, disk-usage

I'm running out of disk, but don't know what is using it up.  DiskUsageAnalyzer can't see the problem either.

More Details:

`df` shows the disk getting full

```
$ df -k /
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      483429920 447182672  11667308  98% /
```

but `du` shows only 68.9 G used (far less than the 447G shown by `df`.)

```
$ sudo du -sk /
du: cannot access '/run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied
du: cannot access '/proc/12251/task/12251/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/12251/task/12251/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/12251/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/12251/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
68915724    /
```

The same thing can be seen in Disk Usage Analyzer (`sudo baobab`).  When started, it shows a near full filesystem that I can select for analysis

```
 `filesystem root / 43.8 GB available 495 GB total
```

but clicking on that filesystem to analyze usage shows that / uses only 57.1 GB. **and leaves me stuck trying to figure out how to clear my disk space**

How can I find out what is using the space if I can't trust `baobab` or `du` to find it?

System details:

```
$ uname -s -r -v 
Linux 4.15.0-34-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 27 15:21:48 UTC 2018
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: Glad you solved the problem as noted in answer below. Next time though can you use `df -h` (h is for human) to make it easier to read?

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be related to https://serverfault.com/questions/315181/df-says-disk-is-full-but-it-is-not.

I had a very large Xorg log file that I had to delete.  After the delete, the difference between `df` and `du` arose.

Reboot reaped the space and solved the problem.